# I want to update the duplicate table entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table of `fav_tweet_ids`. in which I catch the people's favorite `tweet_ids`. I see many people like the same tweet, and in column I see a lot of same `tweet_ids`. I want to select all the those rows and also I want to update all those rows.

My columns are

`id`, `username`, `tweet_id`,`date`, `processing`, `status`, `favs_status`.

I want to update `status`=0 and `processing`=1 and `favs_status` = 0.

this is sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `sent_retweet_tweet_ids` (`id`, `username`, `activity_amount`, `tweet_id`, `user_id`, `date`, `processing`, `status`, `favs_status`) VALUES
(1, 'Funky_Kudi', '55', '763249955360411648', '1', '2016-08-10 08:51:29', 0, 1, '1'),
(2, 'sumimol12high', '55', '763249263375749120', '2', '2016-08-10 09:30:18', 0, 1, '1'),
(3, 'sumimol12high', '55', '763245287338946560', '2', '2016-08-10 09:43:38', 0, 1, '1'),
(4, 'gorgeousupneja', '55', '763249911668285440', '3', '2016-08-10 10:06:28', 0, 1, '1'),
(5, 'gorgeousupneja', '55', '763247421744934913', '3', '2016-08-10 10:19:58', 0, 1, '1'),
(6, 'gorgeousupneja', '55', '763243340410347520', '3', '2016-08-10 10:33:20', 0, 1, '1'),
(7, 'gorgeousupneja', '55', '762979902995898368', '3', '2016-08-10 10:46:42', 0, 1, '1'),
(8, 'sumanphogat123', '55', '763249181649674240', '4', '2016-08-10 11:00:08', 0, 1, '1'),
(9, 'sumanphogat123', '55', '763245117243330560', '4', '2016-08-10 11:13:28', 0, 1, '1'),
(10, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '763317390981537792', '5', '2016-08-10 11:26:47', 0, 1, '1'),
(11, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '763251799356649472', '5', '2016-08-10 11:40:14', 0, 1, '1'),
(12, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '763250442377715712', '5', '2016-08-10 11:53:39', 0, 1, '1'),
(13, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '763250231383248896', '5', '2016-08-10 12:07:39', 0, 1, '1'),
(14, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '763248103868796928', '5', '2016-08-10 12:21:17', 0, 1, '1'),
(15, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '763244138926055424', '5', '2016-08-10 12:34:44', 0, 1, '1'),
(16, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '762994137981345793', '5', '2016-08-10 12:48:05', 0, 1, '1'),
(17, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '762991537307291648', '5', '2016-08-10 13:01:27', 0, 1, '1'),
(18, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '762991427672428544', '5', '2016-08-10 13:15:07', 0, 1, '1'),
(19, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '762988076205420544', '5', '2016-08-10 13:28:35', 0, 1, '1'),
(20, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '762986428691124224', '5', '2016-08-10 13:41:53', 0, 1, '1'),
(21, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '762972461356810240', '5', '2016-08-10 13:55:17', 0, 1, '1'),
(22, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '762969531958435840', '5', '2016-08-10 14:08:43', 0, 1, '1'),
(23, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '762965164098334721', '5', '2016-08-10 14:22:11', 0, 1, '1'),
(24, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '762958117017571328', '5', '2016-08-10 14:35:27', 0, 1, '1'),
(25, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '762921670772346880', '5', '2016-08-10 14:50:37', 0, 1, '1'),
(26, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '762921082479218689', '5', '2016-08-10 15:04:02', 0, 1, '1'),
(27, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '762920922546184193', '5', '2016-08-10 15:17:28', 0, 1, '1'),
(28, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '762920778568306688', '5', '2016-08-10 15:30:52', 0, 1, '1'),
(29, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '762919750632558597', '5', '2016-08-10 15:44:10', 0, 1, '1'),
(30, 'SforSanjay_', '55', '763365762895482880', '6', '2016-08-10 15:57:33', 0, 1, '1'),
(31, 'SforSanjay_', '55', '763317390998319104', '6', '2016-08-10 16:11:05', 0, 1, '1'),
(32, 'SforSanjay_', '55', '763251799394390020', '6', '2016-08-10 16:24:24', 0, 1, '1'),
(33, 'SforSanjay_', '55', '763250442792939520', '6', '2016-08-10 16:37:42', 0, 1, '1'),
(34, 'SforSanjay_', '55', '763250231534161920', '6', '2016-08-10 16:51:03', 0, 1, '1'),
(35, 'SforSanjay_', '55', '763248962262499330', '6', '2016-08-10 17:04:18', 0, 1, '1'),
(36, 'SforSanjay_', '55', '763244747968417792', '6', '2016-08-10 17:17:49', 0, 1, '1'),
(37, 'SforSanjay_', '55', '762996187880304641', '6', '2016-08-10 17:31:14', 0, 1, '1'),
(38, 'SforSanjay_', '55', '762994507105263616', '6', '2016-08-10 17:44:32', 0, 1, '1'),
(39, 'SforSanjay_', '55', '762991537449865219', '6', '2016-08-10 17:57:48', 0, 1, '1'),
(40, 'SforSanjay_', '55', '762991427710128130', '6', '2016-08-10 18:12:46', 0, 1, '1'),
(41, 'SforSanjay_', '55', '762989346358124544', '6', '2016-08-10 18:26:12', 0, 1, '1'),
(42, 'SforSanjay_', '55', '762986641069789184', '6', '2016-08-10 18:39:27', 0, 1, '1'),
(43, 'SforSanjay_', '55', '762980261801828352', '6', '2016-08-10 18:53:26', 0, 1, '1'),
(44, 'Prakharnaldo', '55', '763365762828337152', '5', '2016-08-10 19:15:23', 0, 1, '1'),
(45, 'SforSanjay_', '55', '763365762895482880', '6', '2016-08-10 19:21:52', 0, 1, '1'),
(46, '_harshyadav', '50', '763245751619256321', '7', '2016-08-10 19:33:57', 0, 1, '1'),
(47, '_harshyadav', '50', '763241871355285504', '7', '2016-08-10 19:40:08', 0, 1, '1'),
(48, '_harshyadav', '50', '763245751619256321', '7', '2016-08-10 19:42:04', 0, 1, '1'),
(49, '_harshyadav', '50', '762979902832250880', '7', '2016-08-10 19:46:47', 0, 1, '1'),
(50, '_harshyadav', '50', '763241871355285504', '7', '2016-08-10 19:47:18', 0, 1, '1'),
(51, '_harshyadav', '50', '762979902832250880', '7', '2016-08-10 19:52:34', 0, 1, '1'),
(52, 'lessbeerplease', '50', '763247672706887681', '8', '2016-08-10 19:57:47', 0, 1, '1'),
(53, 'lessbeerplease', '50', '763243537307725824', '8', '2016-08-10 20:03:25', 0, 1, '1'),
(54, 'romanticgupta', '50', '763248893035442176', '9', '2016-08-10 20:08:43', 0, 1, '1'),
(55, 'romanticgupta', '50', '763244621354954753', '9', '2016-08-10 20:14:25', 0, 1, '1'),
(56, 'MUFCabhishek', '50', '763247987829141504', '10', '2016-08-10 20:19:46', 0, 1, '1'),
(57, 'MUFCabhishek', '50', '763243972357656576', '10', '2016-08-10 20:25:08', 0, 1, '1'),
(58, 'london_thumakda', '50', '763247527550484480', '11', '2016-08-10 20:30:22', 0, 1, '1'),
(59, 'london_thumakda', '50', '763243437407739909', '11', '2016-08-10 20:35:41', 0, 1, '1'),
(60, 'tanya_lazy', '50', '763249856316080128', '12', '2016-08-10 20:40:58', 0, 1, '1'),
(61, 'tanya_lazy', '50', '763245537055371264', '12', '2016-08-10 20:46:15', 0, 1, '1'),
(62, 'sjoshi324', '50', '763249112917635072', '13', '2016-08-10 20:51:54', 0, 1, '1'),
(63, 'sjoshi324', '50', '763244927346151424', '13', '2016-08-10 20:57:10', 0, 1, '1'),
(64, 'sjoshi324', '50', '763244856223404036', '13', '2016-08-10 21:02:22', 0, 1, '1'),
(65, 'ramvaish123', '50', '763248357439578112', '14', '2016-08-10 21:07:46', 0, 1, '1'),
(66, 'ramvaish123', '50', '763244310477303808', '14', '2016-08-10 21:13:09', 0, 1, '1'),
(67, 'divy4nshu', '50', '763365762731876352', '15', '2016-08-10 21:18:22', 0, 1, '1'),
(68, 'divy4nshu', '50', '763317390889267200', '15', '2016-08-10 21:23:39', 0, 1, '1'),
(69, 'divy4nshu', '50', '763251794940002304', '15', '2016-08-10 21:28:58', 0, 1, '1'),
(70, 'divy4nshu', '50', '763250438858690560', '15', '2016-08-10 21:34:16', 0, 1, '1'),
(71, 'divy4nshu', '50', '763250230250704896', '15', '2016-08-10 21:39:33', 0, 1, '1'),
(72, 'divy4nshu', '50', '763247066973962240', '15', '2016-08-10 21:44:45', 0, 1, '1'),
(73, 'divy4nshu', '50', '763243048851693568', '15', '2016-08-10 21:49:55', 0, 1, '1'),
(74, 'divy4nshu', '50', '762992996233031681', '15', '2016-08-10 21:55:13', 0, 1, '1'),
(75, 'divy4nshu', '50', '762991537256968192', '15', '2016-08-10 22:00:26', 0, 1, '1'),
(76, 'divy4nshu', '50', '762991427810889728', '15', '2016-08-10 22:05:40', 0, 1, '1'),
(77, 'divy4nshu', '50', '762986781977419777', '15', '2016-08-10 22:11:02', 0, 1, '1'),
(78, 'divy4nshu', '50', '762983290366156800', '15', '2016-08-10 22:16:24', 0, 1, '1'),
(79, 'divy4nshu', '50', '762975732922404865', '15', '2016-08-10 22:21:40', 0, 1, '1'),
(80, 'divy4nshu', '50', '762969531773890562', '15', '2016-08-10 22:26:52', 0, 1, '1'),
(81, 'divy4nshu', '50', '762960652876910592', '15', '2016-08-10 22:32:32', 0, 1, '1'),
(82, 'divy4nshu', '50', '762953081378131969', '15', '2016-08-10 22:37:44', 0, 1, '1'),
(83, 'divy4nshu', '50', '762948815707975680', '15', '2016-08-10 22:42:56', 0, 1, '1'),
(84, 'divy4nshu', '50', '762921669740498944', '15', '2016-08-10 22:48:09', 0, 1, '1'),
(85, 'divy4nshu', '50', '762921081539747840', '15', '2016-08-10 22:53:27', 0, 1, '1'),
(86, 'divy4nshu', '50', '762920921585758209', '15', '2016-08-10 22:58:40', 0, 1, '1'),
```

Comment: (1) Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  (2) Fix the tags.  "mysqli" is not normally used with SQL Server.

Comment: You say you want to update all rows except 1, but don't say anything about what determines which row not to update.

Comment: First I want to select all duplicate rows on the basis of `tweet_id`. and then from those duplicate rows i want to update the dublicate row's `status`=0 and `processing`=1 and `favs_status` = 0.

Comment: sample data is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
       *
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tweet_id, user_id ORDER BY id) as RowNum
    FROM
       fav_tweet_ids
WHERE
   fav_status = 1
)

UPDATE cte 
    SET processing = 1
       ,status = 0
       ,fav_status = 0
WHERE
    RowNum > 1
```

There are a few ways but this is one using an updatable common table expression which makes it really simple.  The other ways is to first find all of the duplicate tweet_ids and then update with a join back to that.

MySQL version to update all but 1 row as desired.  If you want all rows of user/tweet combination there are easier methods this is more than likely what you want to keep.  This assumes you can use mysql variables:

Edited to update based on tweet_id only not users

```
UPDATE sent_retweet_tweet_ids u
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT
      id
      ,@rownum:=IF((@prevtweet = t.tweet_id), @rownum + 1, 1) as RowNum
      ,@prevtweet:= t.tweet_id
    FROM
       sent_retweet_tweet_ids t
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0, @prevtweet:=0) var
    WHERE
        t.fav_status = 1
    ORDER BY
        t.date
    ) r
    ON u.id = r.id
    AND r.RowNum > 1
SET
  u.processing = 1
  ,u.status = 0
  ,u.fav_status = 0
```

SQL Fiddle examples:

Update only when user likes the tweet more than once: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42fb74/1

Update 9 or 10 users when more than 1 like the same tweet: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31c9e

Comment: Does this select the duplicate rows on the basis of `tweet_id` first ?

Comment: It will look at duplicate twee_id by user_id combinations.  So it will only update a user that has more than 1 like for the same tweet.  Note your test data id not have a single case of this or even more than 1 user liking the same tweet.

Comment: No it does not work on mysql, it is an answer for sql-server, oracle, postgressql as sql-server was tagged

Comment: I added an answer for mysql

Comment: Sir thanks alot. But can you please remove this `t.fav_status = 1` ? because i just want to sort all duplicate tweet ids whether people  `t.fav_status ` is 1 or not.

Comment: then just remove the where statement. So the reality is you want to only allow 1 (the first) record per tweet_id to stand as it is regardless of status or fav_status and set every subsequent record for the tweet_id to Processing = 1?  this is way different than what you originally asked but yes just remove the where statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122224/discussion-between-tech-kid-and-matt).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CTE` with `ROW_NUMBER` to identify the duplicates. Then `UPDATE` the `CTE` records having a value of `ROW_NUMBER` that is greater to one:

```sql
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT processing, status, favs_status,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tweet_id ORDER BY date) AS rn
   FROM fav_tweet_ids
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET processing = 1, status = 0, favs_status = 0
WHERE rn > 1
```

The `UPDATE` is propagated to the real table records that correspond to the selected `CTE` records.

Comment: does it find the duplicate rows ?

Comment: @TechKid Yes, it does. It updates *all* duplicates *but* the one having the earliest `date` value.

Comment: this gives error of  `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT processing, status, favs_status,
          ROW_NUMBER(' at line 1`

Comment: @TechKid MySQL? But you have tagged SQL Server.

Comment: ops... can you please help me with mysql ?

Comment: Pardon please i'm really noob.

Comment: @TechKid which is it mysql or sql-server or another platform? Also, I just noted both Giorgos and I assumed you wanted 1 favorite record to stay as it was but in your narrative you don't actually say that do you want every occurrence to be updated or only the duplicates?  Giorgos great minds think alike I got in there only a few seconds ahead but upon re-reading the question I believe the uniqueness is to be on tweet_id, user_id not tweet alone.

Comment: @Matt it is phpmyadmin. my question is that i want to select all the rows those have same tweet_id. and then i want to update those rows's few columns that i mentioned in question.

Comment: TechKid that didn't answer my question so I will try a different route.  Say you have 1 user that liked the same tweet 3 times do you want all 3 rows to be updated with the values you said or only 2 of the 3 rows?  Next you keep saying rows with same tweet_id, but if you don't take into account user you be updating any time more than 1 person likes the same tweet is that what you want or only when the same person likes the tweet more than once?

Comment: for example there are 10 users liked the same tweet_id so the rows are 10. I want to update 9 out of 10.